# How to create mapping of dataframe columns with new column names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to create a column mapping for dataframe columns, this mapping depending on the dataframe schema.

eg.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 2), ("Bob", 5)], ("name", "age"))
df.show()
+-----+---+
| name|age|
+-----+---+
|Alice|  2|
|  Bob|  5|
+-----+---+
```

I want to create map with renamed column. I want to use this map to extract the renamed names in the further code.(I have to create mapping because my schema is dynamic.)

```
col_map={"name":"new_name","age":"new_age"}
```

when ever I df in my further code I should be always able to read columns new_name and new_age etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.alias()` for dynamically change the dataframe column names based on the `map`.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Alice", 2), ("Bob", 5)], ("name", "age"))

df.show(10,False)

col_map={"name":"new_name","age":"new_age"}

df.select([col(f).alias(col_map[f'{f}']) for f in df.columns]).show(10,False)
#
#+-----+---+
#|name |age|
#+-----+---+
#|Alice|2  |
#|Bob  |5  |
#+-----+---+
#
#+--------+-------+
#|new_name|new_age|
#+--------+-------+
#|Alice   |2      |
#|Bob     |5      |
#+--------+-------+
```

Comment: @noyNull I try to modify it like this `df.select([f.col(n).alias({n: f"new_{n}" for n in df.columns})])` but it can not find n. Do yo know how to do it/